# Printing shortest path b/w given nodes using modified floyd warshall

Tags: c++, algorithm, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I read the approach given by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to print the shortes path b/w two given points in a graph by modifying Floyd Warshall algorithm . I coded this, but its not really giving the expected output :

1. Initialize all the elements in `minimumDistanceMatrix[i][j]` to respective weights in the graph and all the elements in the matrix `shortestPathCalculatorMatrix [i][j]` to -1.
2. Then :

   ```
   // Find shortest path using Floyd–Warshall algorithm

   for ( unsigned int k = 0 ; k < getTotalNumberOfCities() ; ++ k)
      for ( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < getTotalNumberOfCities() ; ++ i)
         for ( unsigned int j = 0 ; j < getTotalNumberOfCities() ; ++ j)
             if ( minimumDistanceMatrix[i][k] + minimumDistanceMatrix[k][j] < minimumDistanceMatrix[i][j] )
             {
                   minimumDistanceMatrix[i][j] = minimumDistanceMatrix[i][k] + minimumDistanceMatrix[k][j];
                   shortestPathCalculatorMatrix [i][j] =  k;
             }
   ```
3. Then :

   ```
   void CitiesMap::findShortestPathListBetween(int source , int destination) 
   {
        if( source == destination || source < 0 || destination < 0)
           return;

        if( INFINITY == getShortestPathBetween(source,destination) )
           return ;

        int intermediate = shortestPathCalculatorMatrix[source][destination];

        if( -1 == intermediate )
        {
           pathCityList.push_back( destination );
           return ;
        }

        else
        {
           findShortestPathListBetween( source, intermediate ) ;
           pathCityList.push_back(intermediate);
           findShortestPathListBetween( intermediate, destination ) ;

           return ;
        }
   }
   ```

P.S: `pathCityList` is a vector which is assumed to be empty before a call to `findShortestPathListBetween` is made. At the end of this call, this vector has all the intermediate nodes in it.

Can someone point out where I might be going wrong ?

Comment: You should provide a short sample of the input and output of your code. Or at least provide a description of what the output you get look like.

Comment: There’s really no modification at all necessary – Floyd–Warshall’s algorithm gives you the shortest paths directly (the Wikipedia article is highly misleading; Robert Floyd’s formulation gave the length, Warshall’s gave the paths; together, they give both). But if you’re only interested in *one* shortest path, this algorithm isn’t appropriate anyway, there are more efficient ones (Dijkstra’s algorithm).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am interested in printing the actual path and not the path length which normally Floyd Warshal provides, and hence the modification.

Comment: @Amit See my modified comment. The Wikipedia article is wrong, FW, in its canonical form, *does* provide both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s much easier (and more direct) not to iterate over indices but over vertices. Furthermore, each predecessor (usually denoted `π`, not `next`), needs to point to its, well, *predecessor*, not the current temporary vertex.

Given a |*V*|×|*V*| adjacency matrix `dist` for the distances, initialised to infinity, and a |*V*|×|*V*| adjacency matrix `next` to with pointers to vertices,

```
for each vertex v
    dist[v, v] ← 0
for each edge (u,v)
    dist[u, v] ← w(u,v)  // the weight of the edge (u,v)
    next[u, v] ← u

for each vertex k
    for each vertex i
        for each vertex j
            if dist[i, k] + dist[k, j] < dist[i, j] then
                dist[i, j] ← dist[i, k] + dist[k, j]
                next[i, j] ← next[k, j]
```

Note that I’ve changed the three nested loops to iterate over vertices not indices, and I’ve fixed the last line to refer to the previous node rather than any intermediate node.

An implementation of the above which looks almost like the pseudocode can be found, for instance, in [`scipy.sparse.csgraph`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/12fe2866a9d489d2e4eabd279d1abb930a0c96b6/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_shortest_path.pyx#L321).

Path reconstruction starts at the end (`j` in the code below) and jumps to the predecessor of `j` (at `next[i, j]`) until it reaches `i`.

```
function path(i, j)
    if i = j then
        write(i)
    else if next[i, j] = NIL then
        write("no path exists")
    else
        path(i, next[i, j])
        write(j)
```

Comment: What should I initialize the matrix `next[i][j]` with ? And the only place where this matrix is modified is the statement `next[i][j] ← next[k][j]`. Wouldn't it just keep on overwriting the default values from one location to another location of the same matrix ?

Comment: @Amit Good observation, forgot to mention that (although the linked page mentions that, albeit not in the pseudocode, just the Java implementation). I’ll add that, gimme a sec …

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but the above code is flawed .... it should not be `next[i][j]=next[k][j]` but the correct code for finding this is `next[i][j]=next[i][k]`

Try it yourself on a sample input and you will get to know why this works  and why the previous one is wrong

Comment: Add more description

Answer (score 0):

Here is the below implementation. [Why don't try a problem on it!](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc051/tasks/abc051_d)  Enjoy CP!!

```
   // g[][] is the graph
   // next[i][j] stores vertex next to i in the shortest path between (i,j)
      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
          if(g[i][j]==0)g[i][j]=inf;  // there is no edge b/w (i,j)
          else next[i][j]=j;    // if there is an edge b/w i and j then j should be next to i
        }
      }

      for(int k=1;k<=n;k++){
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
          for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
            if(g[i][j]>g[i][k]+g[k][j]){
              g[i][j]=g[i][k]+g[k][j];
              next[i][j]=next[i][k];  // we found a vertx k next to i which further decrease the shortest path b/w (i,j) so updated it
            }
          }
        }
      }
      // for printing path
      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++){
          int u=i,v=j;
          print(u+" ");
          while(u!=v){
            u=next[u][v];
            print(u+" ");
          }
          print("\n");
        }
      }
```